# gitignore pattern doesn't work without double stars

Tags: git, gitignore

This pattern works properly:

```
**/Assets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*
```

But this pattern doesn't:

```
Assets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*
```

As far as I know, these two patterns are equivalent. What might be the problem here?

Comment: Where is your gitignore? in your root folder?

Comment: @CodeWizard yes, it is in the root folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As far as I know, these two patterns are equivalent.

They aren't.

Git has a poorly-documented sneaky feature (bug? annoyance? call it whatever you like, though it's meant as a feature) in which a glob pattern in a `.gitignore` file is sometimes anchored or rooted—it's not clear what word to use here—and sometimes not.  I think this is best explained by example.

Suppose you have the following files:

```
/a
/b
/dir/a
/dir/b
/dir/sub/a
/dir/sub/b
```

That is, the top level directory has two files, `a` and `b`, and one directory `dir`.  Inside `dir` there are two files `a` and `b`, and another directory `sub`, and in that last one there are two files `a` and `b`.

Listing `a` in your `.gitignore` means *ignore all files named `a`*,<sup>1</sup> so that covers three of the six files.

However, listing `/a` in your `.gitignore` means *ignore file named `a` in the top level only*, i.e., ignore just one file.

It's the presence of the slash at *any position other than the end* that triggers this feature, so listing `dir/a` in your top-level file means *ignore file named `a` in the `dir` directory only*, i.e., just `/dir/a`.  If we made a new file `dir/sub/dir/a`, that would *not* be ignored: `dir/a` means the same as `/dir/a`.

One might expect only a *leading* slash to do this, but in fact, it's *any* slash, *except at the end*, that does this.  The *except at the end* part means that if you list `sub/` in your top level `.gitignore`, Git will ignore both files inside `dir/sub`, because the slash is removed from the end before applying the "contains a slash" rule, then put back on the end for the "matches a directory" rule.

The result is that if you mean to ignore `Assets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*` at *any* level—not just the current level (wherever this particular `.gitignore` file lives within your work-tree)—you need the `**/` prefix.

Note that you can have a `.gitignore` file at *each* level, so you could just find directories named `Editor`, and if they are in an `Assets/Plugins/` containing directory, create a `.gitignore` here that lists `JetBrains*`.  That would have the same effect as writing `**/Assets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*` at the top level.

---

<sup>1</sup>*Ignore* is really the wrong verb.  A file won't be ignored if it's already tracked; listing a file in `.gitignore` means *don't complain about this file if it's untracked, and don't automatically add it with an en-masse "add all files" command.*  It also gives Git permission to clobber the file in certain cases.  But calling the file `.git-dont-complain-about-untracked-and-dont-auto-add-and-sometimes-feel-free-to-clobber-these-files` would be unweidly, so we say "ignore"...

Comment: Honestly, I think this is a bug. It should be fixed. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: It probably would make more sense to root/anchor the glob if and only if it starts with `/` rather than if it contains `/`. The range of names you can express would remain exactly the same. Whether you can convince the Git folks of this is a separate question entirely, though.

Answer (score 1):

`**/Assets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*`
Will ignore the path doesn't matter what is the root folder of the Assets which mean it can be nested.

`Assets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*`
Will ignore the path statring from **the current** folder

`**/` means that it can be "nested" inside any folder under the location of the current path

Comment: The gitignore is in the root folder of the repository